# Output not containing all words

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to print each word of the quote in a new line but for some reason the last word "fast" won't get printed. Can you tell me that reason and the fix? Thank you.

[below link contains the image of the code, somehow stackoverflow made it impossible for me to paste the code "here"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODkif.png)

Comment: Because the last char in your input is not a space `" "`. Think through it step-by-step. Btw, `print('\n'.join(quote.split()))` is the short version ;)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but can you tell me why it doesn't go to the letter "f" right after it hits the " " after "run"?

Comment: I would assume it does. `Name` just never gets printed again.

Comment: You're right, i see it now... Thanks again!